# Could not an adapted RASSOR appear to be crucial for the Perseverance rover to find possible biosignatures on Mars?

Tags: mars, design-alternative, perseverance, astrobiology

Is it not very likely that most of the material that could contain possible biosignatures, like clays and carbonate containing minerals, will be below a layer of dust or regolith on Mars ?

That the material the rover can examine on the surface is 'only' the top of the iceberg ?

The [RIMFAX radar imager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIMFAX) onboard Perseverance could help in localizing such material below the surface.

But because of the low gravity on Mars, digging to the possible biosignatures would be difficult because a traditional excavator would not provide enough reaction force to penetrate into the regolith.

[image: RASSOR]

Credits: NASA Kennedy Space Center

From [this article](https://ntts-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/t2p/prod/t2media/tops/pdf/KSC-TOPS-7.pdf):

> RASSOR uses counterrotating bucket drums on opposing arms to provide near-zero horizontal and minimal vertical net reaction force so that excavation is not reliant on the traction or weight of the mobility system to provide a reaction force to counteract the excavation force in low-gravity environments.

[image: Drums]

Credits: NASA/Kim Shiflett

On [the image above from this article](https://nasa.gov/feature/help-nasa-design-a-robot-to-dig-on-the-moon) you can see the scoops around the circumference of the cylinders.

So with some modifications, like brushes on the drums to remove the lowest part of a dust or regolith layer from a layer with possible biosignatures, would [RASSOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NASA_robots#RASSOR) not be very suitable to assist Perseverance ?

Comment: For removing the smaller sized components of regolith it most likely would be beneficial. The query I have is what happens when the RASSOR encounters larger rocks, as it will?

Comment: @Fred I think with brushes Rassor could clean the rock and Perseverance could examine it.

Comment: @Fred Yes, RASSOR would have to be sensitive enough not to damage the scoops.

Comment: Not damaging the RASSOR with defensive mechanisms is one thing & it is a good design feature. The other aspect of encountering large rocks is progress in removing regolith at a location with large rocks potentially stops because the RASSOR most likely won't be able to deal the rocks, by either getting rid of it via its mechanisms or by moving it out of the way.

Comment: I get the impression, from reading many posts here, that some people think that lunar & Martian regolith is small sized material; effectively sand & maybe some pebbles, where in fact all lunar regolith & much of Mars' regolith is the result of impact crater ejected material. The size distribution of such material ranges from dust sized particles to boulders and it's all mixed up with one lot of ejected material covering another lot, or more. ...

Comment: On the Moon it will be undifferentiated, whereas on Mars, because it once presumably had an atmosphere, with weather & moving surface waters will have locations that will have layered & differentiated sediments as part of its regolith.

Comment: @Fred So what about the delta-like deposit in Jezero crater, where sediment was carried by water and deposited in a lake ? Depending of the force of the water, there could be layers with no large rocks. But could RASSOR be powerful enough to scrape of sedimentary rock ? Could it handle sandstone for instance, or clay, gypsum or carbonate ?

Comment: That would depend on the strength of each rock formation type & how much breakout force the RASSOR could generate & whether that was sufficient to overcome the strength & hardness of each formation type. My suspicion is it may not - the RASSOR appears "lightweight" & for it to be able to stay together when digging, it needs a certain amount of robustness within its frame & components. ...

Comment: ... Tungsten carbine on the cutting edges of the RASSOR would help. From what I've seen of drilling attempts on Mars, & at Jezero, the sediments appear to be compact & solid. A drill would be better suited to cut through such rock. My impression is the RASSOR might be better suited to loose, unconsolidated, smaller sized regolith.

Comment: @Fred This article, https://phys.org/news/2021-10-floor-jezero-crater-mars-sustained.html tells about the drilling attempts. The core of the first drilling was pulverized and scientists think the igneous rock became so altered and weakened from interactions with water that the vibrations and strength of the drill pulverized the sample.

Comment: The article also states, "Scientists then targeted another rock that appeared more resistant to weathering, and Perseverance was able to successfully collect two core samples—the first in its sample collection". They were unlucky with the first attempt but lucky with the other attempts elsewhere. This does not surprise me. The degree of weathering is not always uniform for rocks even in close proximity to one another. It's just how geology is - Murphy's Second Law: *Mother Nature is a b~tch* (from a poster in the Physics Lab during my final year of high school, some time ago).

Comment: When dealing with geology, its always advantage to be able to "kick the dirt" - go the the location of interest, test the hardness of the surface by kicking it with the heel of a boot, look at the layout of the land & do whatever else is required to get first hand experience of what is being dealt with. On celestial bodies such a the Moon & Mars we can't do that now. We did it with the Moon back in the late 1960s & early 1970s & it's helped to a limited extent with our understanding of the Moon. With Mars we take photographs & send rovers to take measurements of particular surface features ...

Comment: We then send other probes to take another set of photographs & take another set of measurements. The equipment each probe has, has sometimes been designed using our best  interpretation of data collected previously. Sometimes we get it wrong & an item fails to perform as anticipated. By simply looking at a rock target we don't know how it will behave if it were to be drilled or dug. It' a trial & error situation. From what I see of the RASSOR, it look too flimsy to use on anything else other than loose unconsolidated material.

Comment: @Fred O.k, loose material enough on Mars for RASSOR ! And I'm glad with the pulverizing, the more weathering of rocks, the more chances for (past) life, I guess.